# Convert multiple string stored in a variable into a single list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I hope everyone is doing well.
I need a little help where I need to get all the strings from a variable and need to store into a single list in python.
For example - 
I have json file from where I am getting ids and all the ids are getting stored into a variable called id as below when I run print(id)

```
17298626-991c-e490-bae6-47079c6e2202
17298496-19bd-2f89-7b5f-881921abc632
17298698-3e17-7a9b-b337-aacfd9483b1b
172986ac-d91d-c4ea-2e50-d53700480dd0
172986d0-18aa-6f51-9c62-6cb087ad31e5
172986f4-80f0-5c21-3aee-12f22a5f4322
17298712-a4ac-7b36-08e9-8512fa8322dd
17298747-8cc6-d9d0-8d05-50adf228c029
1729875c-050f-9a99-4850-bb0e6ad35fb0
1729875f-0d50-dc94-5515-b4891c40d81c
17298761-c26b-3ce5-e77e-db412c38a5b4
172987c8-2b5d-0d94-c365-e8407b0a8860
1729881a-e583-2b54-3a52-d092020d9c1d
1729881c-64a2-67cf-d561-6e5e38ed14cb
172987ec-7a20-7eb6-3ebe-a9fb621bb566
17298813-7ac4-258b-d6f9-aaf43f9147b1
17298813-f1ef-d28a-0817-5f3b86c3cf23
17298828-b62b-9ee6-248b-521b0663226e
17298825-7449-2fcb-378e-13671cb4688a
```

I want these all values to be stored into a single list.
Can some please help me out with this.

Below is the code I am using:

```
import json
with open('requests.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
print(type(data))
for i in data:
     if 'traceId' in i:
         id = i['traceId']
         newid = id.split()
         #print(type(newid))
         print(newid)
```

And below is my json file looks like:

```
[
   {
      "id": "376287298-hjd8-jfjb-khkf-6479280283e9",
      "submittedTime": 1591692502558,
      "traceId": "17298626-991c-e490-bae6-47079c6e2202",
      "userName": "ABC",
      "onlyChanged": true,
      "description": "Not Required",
      "startTime": 1591694487929,
      "result": "NONE",
      "state": "EXECUTING",
      "paused": false,
      "application": {
         "id": "16b22a09-a840-f4d9-f42a-64fd73fece57",
         "name": "XYZ"
      },
      "applicationProcess": {
         "id": "dihihdosfj9279278yrie8ue",
         "name": "Deploy",
         "version": 12
      },
      "environment": {
         "id": "fkjdshkjdshglkjdshgldshldsh03r937837",
         "name": "DEV"
      },
      "snapshot": {
         "id": "djnglkfdglki98478yhgjh48yr844h",
         "name": "DEV_snapshot"
      },

   },
   {
      "id": "17298495-f060-3e9d-7097-1f86d5160789",
      "submittedTime": 1591692844597,
      "traceId": "17298496-19bd-2f89-7b5f-881921abc632",
      "userName": "UYT,
      "onlyChanged": true,
      "startTime": 1591692845543,
      "result": "NONE",
      "state": "EXECUTING",
      "paused": false,
      "application": {
         "id": "osfodsho883793hgjbv98r3098w",
         "name": "QA"
      },
      "applicationProcess": {
         "id": "owjfoew028r2uoieroiehojehfoef",
         "name": "EDC",
         "version": 5
      },
      "environment": {
         "id": "16cf69c5-4194-e557-707d-0663afdbceba",
         "name": "DTESTU"
      },

   }
 ]
```

From where I am trying to get the traceId.

Comment: Call `list.append ()` in a loop

Comment: id_list =id.split()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use simple `split` method like the follwing:

```
ids = '''17298626-991c-e490-bae6-47079c6e2202 17298496-19bd-2f89-7b5f-881921abc632 17298698-3e17-7a9b-b337-aacfd9483b1b 172986ac-d91d-c4ea-2e50-d53700480dd0 172986d0-18aa-6f51-9c62-6cb087ad31e5 172986f4-80f0-5c21-3aee-12f22a5f4322 17298712-a4ac-7b36-08e9-8512fa8322dd 17298747-8cc6-d9d0-8d05-50adf228c029 1729875c-050f-9a99-4850-bb0e6ad35fb0 1729875f-0d50-dc94-5515-b4891c40d81c 17298761-c26b-3ce5-e77e-db412c38a5b4 172987c8-2b5d-0d94-c365-e8407b0a8860 1729881a-e583-2b54-3a52-d092020d9c1d 1729881c-64a2-67cf-d561-6e5e38ed14cb 172987ec-7a20-7eb6-3ebe-a9fb621bb566 17298813-7ac4-258b-d6f9-aaf43f9147b1 17298813-f1ef-d28a-0817-5f3b86c3cf23 17298828-b62b-9ee6-248b-521b0663226e 17298825-7449-2fcb-378e-13671cb4688a'''

l = ids.split(" ")
print(l)
```

This will give the following result, I assumed that the separator needed is simple space  you can adjust properly:

```
['17298626-991c-e490-bae6-47079c6e2202', '17298496-19bd-2f89-7b5f-881921abc632', '17298698-3e17-7a9b-b337-aacfd9483b1b', '172986ac-d91d-c4ea-2e50-d53700480dd0', '172986d0-18aa-6f51-9c62-6cb087ad31e5', '172986f4-80f0-5c21-3aee-12f22a5f4322', '17298712-a4ac-7b36-08e9-8512fa8322dd', '17298747-8cc6-d9d0-8d05-50adf228c029', '1729875c-050f-9a99-4850-bb0e6ad35fb0', '1729875f-0d50-dc94-5515-b4891c40d81c', '17298761-c26b-3ce5-e77e-db412c38a5b4', '172987c8-2b5d-0d94-c365-e8407b0a8860', '1729881a-e583-2b54-3a52-d092020d9c1d', '1729881c-64a2-67cf-d561-6e5e38ed14cb', '172987ec-7a20-7eb6-3ebe-a9fb621bb566', '17298813-7ac4-258b-d6f9-aaf43f9147b1', '17298813-f1ef-d28a-0817-5f3b86c3cf23', '17298828-b62b-9ee6-248b-521b0663226e', '17298825-7449-2fcb-378e-13671cb4688a']
```

## Edit

You get list of lists because each iteration you read only 1 `id`, so what you need to do is to initiate an empty list and append each id to it in the following way:

```
l = []
for i in data
    if 'traceId' in i:
         id = i['traceId']
         l.append(id)
```

Comment: Hi @David S thanks for answering the questions.
I have tried i but it gives me something like below:

['17298626-991c-e490-bae6-47079c6e2202']
['17298496-19bd-2f89-7b5f-881921abc632']
['17298698-3e17-7a9b-b337-aacfd9483b1b']
['172986ac-d91d-c4ea-2e50-d53700480dd0']
['172986d0-18aa-6f51-9c62-6cb087ad31e5']
['172986f4-80f0-5c21-3aee-12f22a5f4322']
['17298712-a4ac-7b36-08e9-8512fa8322dd']
['17298747-8cc6-d9d0-8d05-50adf228c029']
['1729875c-050f-9a99-4850-bb0e6ad35fb0']

It is giving me a single list for single value.

Comment: @krishnanshutyagi so the problem is that the way you introduced the question was wrong, can you tell me what data type is your `id`?

Comment: Type of id is 'str'

Comment: @krishnanshutyagi So you need to provide the exact way the `id` looks like in order for to us help you

Comment: I have added some content of my json. Please have a look.

Comment: @krishnanshutyagi It works fine with the data you provided. There is something you are doing wrong

Comment: Hey yes It is working fine there was something wrong with my script only.
Thanks for your time David. Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can append the `ids` variable to the list such as,

```
#list declaration
l1=[]

#this must be in your loop
l1.append(ids)
```

Comment: Hi Prathamesh Jadhav,
It gives me None multiple times when I tried it.

Comment: can you put your code in the question so i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you get the `id` as a `str` type value. Using `id.split()` will return a list of all ids in one single Python list, as each id is separated by space here in your example.

```py
id = """17298626-991c-e490-bae6-47079c6e2202 17298496-19bd-2f89-7b5f-881921abc632
        17298698-3e17-7a9b-b337-aacfd9483b1b 172986ac-d91d-c4ea-2e50-d53700480dd0
        172986d0-18aa-6f51-9c62-6cb087ad31e5 172986f4-80f0-5c21-3aee-12f22a5f4322
        17298712-a4ac-7b36-08e9-8512fa8322dd 17298747-8cc6-d9d0-8d05-50adf228c029
        1729875c-050f-9a99-4850-bb0e6ad35fb0 1729875f-0d50-dc94-5515-b4891c40d81c
        17298761-c26b-3ce5-e77e-db412c38a5b4 172987c8-2b5d-0d94-c365-e8407b0a8860
        1729881a-e583-2b54-3a52-d092020d9c1d 1729881c-64a2-67cf-d561-6e5e38ed14cb
        172987ec-7a20-7eb6-3ebe-a9fb621bb566 17298813-7ac4-258b-d6f9-aaf43f9147b1
        17298813-f1ef-d28a-0817-5f3b86c3cf23 17298828-b62b-9ee6-248b-521b0663226e
        17298825-7449-2fcb-378e-13671cb4688a"""
id_list = id.split()
print(id_list)
```

Output:

```
['17298626-991c-e490-bae6-47079c6e2202', '17298496-19bd-2f89-7b5f-881921abc632',
'17298698-3e17-7a9b-b337-aacfd9483b1b', '172986ac-d91d-c4ea-2e50-d53700480dd0',
'172986d0-18aa-6f51-9c62-6cb087ad31e5', '172986f4-80f0-5c21-3aee-12f22a5f4322',
'17298712-a4ac-7b36-08e9-8512fa8322dd', '17298747-8cc6-d9d0-8d05-50adf228c029',
'1729875c-050f-9a99-4850-bb0e6ad35fb0', '1729875f-0d50-dc94-5515-b4891c40d81c',
'17298761-c26b-3ce5-e77e-db412c38a5b4', '172987c8-2b5d-0d94-c365-e8407b0a8860',
'1729881a-e583-2b54-3a52-d092020d9c1d', '1729881c-64a2-67cf-d561-6e5e38ed14cb',
'172987ec-7a20-7eb6-3ebe-a9fb621bb566', '17298813-7ac4-258b-d6f9-aaf43f9147b1',
'17298813-f1ef-d28a-0817-5f3b86c3cf23', '17298828-b62b-9ee6-248b-521b0663226e',
'17298825-7449-2fcb-378e-13671cb4688a']
```

[`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) splits by default with space as a separator. You can use the `sep` argument to use any other separator if needed.

Comment: Hi Ankur,

I have tried it as well but this also given the separate list for each value like below:
['172987ec-7a20-7eb6-3ebe-a9fb621bb566']
['17298813-7ac4-258b-d6f9-aaf43f9147b1']
['17298813-f1ef-d28a-0817-5f3b86c3cf23']
['17298828-b62b-9ee6-248b-521b0663226e']
['17298825-7449-2fcb-378e-13671cb4688a']